# How to resolve type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I am having difficulties in implementing a post request on my flutter app. I kept getting this error. What circumstance does this occur and how can it be fixed?

**Error**

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

**Post Request Function**

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> post(String url, dynamic body,
      {redirectOn401: true}) async {
    MainBloc bloc = Provider.of<MainBloc>(context, listen: false);
    Map<String, String> _headers = await headers(bloc: bloc);

    http.Response response = await http.post(
      BASE_URL + url,
      headers: _headers,
      body: json.encode(body),
    );
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    print(responseJson.toString());
    int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    switch (statusCode) {
      case 200:
      case 201:
        Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
        return data;
        break;

      case 422:
      case 400:
        dynamic data = json.decode(response.body);
        String msg;
        print("response " + data.toString());
        break;
      default:
        dynamic data = json.decode(response.body);
        print("response " + data.toString());
        String msg;
        break;
    }
  }
```

**Expected Api Response**

```
{
    "room_name": "W5u8Bz2oeIMM32I8ZSanreKvwLk2z8xWzXoaaLroom"
}
```

Comment: You can try Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>.from = json.decode(response.body);

Comment: i get same result

Comment: Can you edit your question with some sample data?

Comment: can you add api response?

Comment: you mean the data payload?

Comment: @ajay i just added expected api response